# Getting LiveData values to use with other LiveData values

Tags: java, android, android-livedata

(New to android programming)
I have a `RecyclerView` of subcategories and their corresponding keywords.

like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLIHE.jpg

The subcategories are fetched by observing

```java
subcategoryViewModel.getAllSubcategoriesForCategory(id).observe...
```

(I am using Room), here I have the id available (it is known which category is chosen at the time of creation of the subcategory fragment).

However, I am having troubles calculating the corresponding keywords. The keywords are the names of the articles contained in each subcategory.

In my `ArticleDao` I have a function

```java
LiveData<List<String>> getAllArticleNamesById(int subId);
```

So logically, I just have to get the current subcategory list and get their corresponding keywords in a for loop. 
But how do I do that if both the subcategory list and the keywords list are `LiveData` and I cannot access their values, only their observers can?

I tried putting an observer within an observer but I don't think that's the best idea.

```java
subcategoryViewModel.getAllSubcategoriesForCategory(id).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                new Observer<List<Subcategory>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChanged(List<Subcategory> subcategories) {
                        recyclerAdapter.setSubcategories(subcategories);

                        for (Subcategory sub : subcategories) {
                            articleViewModel.getAllArticleNamesById(sub.getId()).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),
                                    new Observer<List<String>>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onChanged(List<String> strings) {
                                            recyclerAdapter.addToKeywordsList(keywordsIntoString(strings));
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
        });
```

I found some information on `LiveData` Transformations (map, switchmap) but that doesn't really apply to my problem since its supposed to apply a function on `LiveData` when other`LiveData` changes. (at least from what I understand). I just need to access the current subcategory list and work with the values so I can observe the article names.

Ideally, I would need something like this:

```java
for (Subcategory sub : subcategoryList) {
      articleViewModel.getAllArticleNamesById(sub.getId()).observe...
}
```

So my question is, how do I access the subcategories which I'm already observing? Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello @Dominika can you please explain in brief so i can help you more.as per your explanation. i just get you have main list inside each element you have different subcategories right.

Comment: Yes, and each subcategory has its keywords (as you can see in the picture), I need to get the subcategory list so I can get the keywords for each subcategory in the list and show them in the list as the keywords. I just don't know how to access both at the same time as they are LiveData objects.

Comment: Gajdova can you please post  some code here so i can get some idea. I want to know about your Room database structure. as per your description your main have one table and child have also one table right ?

Comment: Main table is Category, then Subcategory (each category contains subcategories), then Article (each subcategory contains articles). What specific code would you be interested in? Cause there's a lot of room code

Comment: Gajdova Please post your observable code. of subcategory and articles both.

Comment: ok I updated the question with the code

Comment: @Dominica This is not right way to do. i think this observer you have to set in adapter.  when on bindviewholder is calling. your second observer or you have to first get all record then you have to bind adapter.

Comment: Gajdova Your problem is solved ?

Comment: I think so, I ended up just observing all articles and filtering them afterwards.

Comment: @Diminika Gajdova Great